# In-app purchase in ios 7 for buy all items

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I have 11 sets of non-consumable with hosted content products, purchase of individual products working successfully.

Next i want to add a button allset, while clicking allset for purchase , multiple products (10 sets) with host content are set as purchased and hosted contents also downloaded.

Is it possible in ios In-App purchase?

Comment: It's better add new product and set price to sum of 10 product. then when user buy this IAP you can disable other product and set full access to user.

Comment: how to download all hosted contents?

Comment: no need to download all products for example if user download number 11 product your app disable all other(10) IAP and full access to user

Comment: purchasing can be avoid using user access. how to download hosted content for each product from itunes store?